# How do me call $\mu_X$ when $X$ is neither continuous nor discrete?

Tags: probability

Let $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ a r.v. on $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$. Let $$\mu_X(A):=\mathbb P\{X\in A\},\quad A\in \mathcal F.$$

- If $\mu_X$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, then $X$ has a density. I.e. there is $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $$\mu_X(A)=\int_A g(x)dx,$$ and $g$ is called density.
- If $X$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. countable sum of Dirac measure, then $X$ has a mass function. I.e. let $\mathcal D$ a countable set and let $$\delta _{\mathcal D}=\sum_{k\in \mathcal D}\delta _k,$$
  where $\delta _k$ is the Dirac mass at $k $. Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $$\mu_X(A)=\int_A f(x)\delta _{\mathcal D}(dx).$$
  Then $f$ is called the mass function of $X$.
- Let $\nu$ be for example the measure defined by $$\nu=m_{[0,1/2]}+\delta _2$$ where $m_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]},$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $\delta _2$ the Dirac mass on $2$. Let $h:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be s.t. $$\mu_X(A)=\int_A h(x)\nu(dx).$$
  How do we call $h$ ?

Comment: The term ``subdensity'' is occasionally used to refer to the absolutely continuous part of a distribution with respect to Lebesuge measure.

Answer (score 2):

For me, $\mu_X$ is always called the **law** or **probability distribution** of the random variable $X$.

When $X$ is continuous, there exists a map $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that for all $A\in\mathcal F$, we have $\mu_X(A)=\int_Af(x)\,dx$. Such a map $f$ is called the **density** of $X$.

When $X$ is discrete, there exists an at most countable set $E\subset\mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb P(X\in E)=1$, and a map $p:E\to\mathbb R$ such that for all $x\in E$, $p(x)=\mathbb P(X=x)$. We then have, for all $A\in\mathcal F$, $\mathbb P(X\in A)=\sum_{x\in E}1_A(x)p(x)=\sum_{x\in E\cap A}p(x)$. Such a map $p$ is called the **mass function** of $X$.

So $\mu_X$ is always the probability distribution. It is closely related to a map called density in the continuous case, or a map called mass function in the discrete case, but they should be distinguished.

EDIT: There is still a confusion in what you wrote. In the continuous case, you have $\mu_X(A)=\int_Ah(x)\,\nu(dx)$ where $\nu(dx)=dx$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$, and in the discrete case you have $\mu_X(A)=\int_Ah(x)\,\nu(dx)$ where $\nu=\sum_{x\in E}\delta_x$ where $E$ is an at most countable subset of $\mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb P(X\in E)=1$. So you rather have $\mu_X(A)=\int_Ah(x)\,\nu(dx)$, where $\nu$ is a measure to be specified. In the continuous case, we saw that $\nu$ is the Lebesgue measure, and in the discrete case it is the counting measure on $E$. So how do you generalise this? In both cases, $\nu$ is such that for all $A\in\mathcal F$, if $\nu(A)=0$, then $\mu_X(A)=0$. We say that $\mu_X$ is **dominated** by $\nu$, and we denote $\mu_X\ll\nu$. By the Radon-Nikodym theorem, there exists a map $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that for all $A\in\mathcal F$, $\mu_X(A)=\int_Ah(x)\,\nu(dx)$. Such a map $h$ is called the **Radon-Nikodym derivative** and can be denoted $d\mu_X/d\nu$.

The continuous case is by definition the case where $\mu_X$ is dominated by the Lebesgue measure, and the Radon-Nikodym derivative is called density. The discrete case is by definition the case where $\mu_X$ is dominated by the counting measure of an at most countable subset of $\mathbb R$, and the Radon-Nikodym derivative if called mass function.

Comment: I edited my question (indeed, I made a confusion).

Comment: For some people, "continuous distribution" means that the cdf is continuous.

Comment: I edited my answer as well. To make it short, $h$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu_X$ with respect to $\nu$.

Comment: @Will if we use " random variable is continuous if its CFD is continuous " then still your second paragraph true?

Comment: @MeetPatel I believe you mean CDF. Then no. A random variable has a density (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) if and only if its CDF is absolutely continuous. So continuity only is not enough. A famous counter-example is given by the Cantor function.